# onChange Event is returning an empty field

Tags: javascript, html

I want to update a id="total_fee" input on changing the values in input fields.

This is my HTML;

```
<td class="'.$bg_trow.$challan_created_shade.'" align="center">
  <div>
    <div style="font-size: 11px;">Actual Fee</div>
    <input type="text" class="small_input_box" id="actual_fee_'.$f['fid'].'" style="background: #EFEFEF; border: 1px solid #000; color: #000;" name="actual_fee" size="5" value="1400" readonly="readonly">
  </div>
  <div>
    <div style="font-size: 11px;">Monthly Fee</div>
    <input onchange="findTotal_'.$f['fid'].'()" type="text" class="small_input_box fee_'.$f['fid'].'" name="monthly_fee" size="5" value="1000">
  </div>
</td>
<td class="'.$bg_trow.$challan_created_shade.'" align="center">
  <div>
    <div style="font-size: 11px;">Paper Money</div>
    <input onchange="findTotal_'.$f['fid'].'()" type="text" class="small_input_box fee_'.$f['fid'].'" name="paper_money_fee" size="5" value="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <div style="font-size: 11px;">Previous Balance</div>
    <input onchange="findTotal_'.$f['fid'].'()" type="text" class="small_input_box fee_'.$f['fid'].'" name="previous_balance" size="5" value="">
  </div>
</td>
<td class="'.$bg_trow.$challan_created_shade.'" align="center">
  <div>
    <div style="font-size: 11px;">Total Fee</div>
    <input type="text" class="small_input_box" style="background: #EFEFEF; border: 1px solid #000; color: #000;" name="total_fee" id="total_fee_'.$f['fid'].'" size="5" value="" readonly="readonly">
  </div>
</td>
```

and this is my JavaScript function;

```
function findTotal_'.$f['fid'].'() {
  const fees = document.querySelectorAll(".fee_'.$f['fid'].'");
  const total = document.querySelector("#total_fee_'.$f['fid'].'");
  let sum = 0;
  fees.forEach((fee) => {
    if (fee.valueAsNumber) {
      sum += fee.valueAsNumber;
    }
  });
  total.value = sum;
}
```

When the values are changed in input field, it is returning zero. I don't know why. Plz help.

Comment: Please check the querySelectors properly to verify if they exist in your code

Comment: @Nevermore: I used fee.value. Now it is getting the input values but it does not getting sum of all the numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay..

I have done it by meself, by changing the javascript function to this;

```
function findTotal_'.$f['fid'].'()
        {
            const fees = document.querySelectorAll(".fee_'.$f['fid'].'");
            const total = document.querySelector("#total_fee_'.$f['fid'].'");
            let sum = 0;
            fees.forEach(fee => {
                if(fee.value)
                {
                    sum += + fee.value;
                }   
            });
            total.value = sum;
        }
```

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fee.value` instead of using `fee.valueAsNumber` and also you should use valid identifiers (name) for your functions ie. the name `findTotal_'.$f['fid'].'` is not a valid one.

Comment: I used fee.value. Now it is getting the input values but it does not getting sum of all the numbers

Comment: Thank You @Hari Ram. I have done it by myself.